# Detecting t-junctions

Tags: graphics, 3d, mesh, triangulation

I need to write a method that check polygon mesh quality. In particular I need to detect T-junctions. Do you know where to start?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Is it close or open mesh ?

Comment: How is your mesh represented?

Comment: C/C++/C#, can be open or closed, 3D points and triangle vertex indices...